# Data type lost while uploading csv/Json data through azure storage explorer

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have a azure table with few columns.Every column has a different data type like Date,double,Guid and string.

When I insert these data into table storage through programming, data is getting saved properly with their respective data type.

Now when I download these data through azure storage explorer download/upload features in the format of Json or CSV and When I am trying to upload these downloaded CSV or Json to another table, all data are getting uploaded successfully but the data type of each column converted into "String" datatype.

So can any body help me to resolve this issue please.

Comment: Azure Storage Explorer - you're referring to a specific tool? Might be an issue with the tool itself. Not a programming question.

Comment: Do all rows have values in all columns? If not, that might be your problem. Since it is a schema less database it can't always figure out the type of a column when not all records have the same layout.

Comment: Yes Peter, All columns have values but with different datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

this issue has been fixed. please install the latest version of the Storage Explorer from storagexplorer.com and retry. You should be able to see the data and type information correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This issue was with previous version of Azure Storage Explore (Azure Storage Explorer 6 Preview).

But in new version of azure storage explorer(Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer V 0.8.2) they have resolved this issue.

The thing is like now when we are exporting any data in CSV or Json from Azure storage explorer they the incorporating the type information as well along with data.